# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo esta consulta:

```
            $existencia = DB::table('SUPER')
                    ->select(DB::raw('SUM(CANTIDAD * CALCULO)'))
                    ->where('PRODUCTO',1228)
                    ->where('SUCURSAL',2)
                    ->whereBetween('FECHA',['01/19/2019','02/19/2019'])->first();
```

que que al hacer  dd($existencia);  me devuelve `+"SUM": "-31.000000"`
pero al hacer una comparación en la vista  `$existencia > 0` me muestra el error.
Como es que se puede convertir este resultado a entero?

Comment: $existencia > 0, es una comparación invalida, ya que uno es un objeto y el otro es un numero.

Comment: Shassain, si por eso busco ayuda aquí como hacer esa comparación. @Aprendiz  probé con eso pero me marca esto: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te propongo la siguiente solución:

- Crea el modelo **`Super`** para que sea la entidad que represente a la tabla de tu base de datos con el mismo nombre, con el siguiente comando:

Creación del modelo

```
php artisan make:model Super
```

Considera la siguiente:

- Si la tabla tiene nombre en singular, entonces en tu modelo deberás declarar la siguiente propiedad:

Propiedad

```
protected $table = "super";
```

- A tu función de reducción **`SUM`** agrégale un alias para poder recuperarla posteriormente, en este caso usaremos el alias de **Total**
- En vez de usar directamente el *facade* **`DB`** puedes sustituirlo por el uso del método **`selectRaw`**
- Cuando intentes comprobar si el valor que te retorna la consulta es mayor a **0**, entonces sigue esta sintaxis:

Código:

```
$propiedad["clave"];
```

Es decir deberás acceder a la propiedad que guarda tu consulta y entre *corchetes* acceder al alias que declaramos mas arriba que es el que nos retorna el valor de la función **`SUM`**

Finalmente tu código debería verse así:

```
$existencia = Super::selectRaw('SUM(CANTIDAD * CALCULO) AS Total')
                    ->where('PRODUCTO',1228)
                    ->where('SUCURSAL',2)
                    ->whereBetween('FECHA',['01/19/2019','02/19/2019'])
                    ->first();
```

Ahora para comprobar si es mayor a cero basta con realizar lo siguiente:

```
if($existencia["Total"] > 0) {
    return "El valor es mayor a 0";
}else{
    return "No es mayor a 0";
}
```

Dando una salida como esta si es que si es mayor a 0:

> El valor es mayor a 0

Comment: Muchas gracias enserio !! esto funcionó. c: